# #1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

Tags: web-deployment, magento2, mysql5, mysql6

I have a **Magento2** website and wanted to deploy on a server. I got the above mentioned error when I tried to import DB copy of a local to the live mySQL server. I found the reason that on local system I have **mySQL 5.6** and **phpMyAdmin 4.4** and on the live server it is lower than 5.6(my hosting does not show which mysql version). and **phpMyAdmin 3.4.11**.
Is there any way to fix the problem? Your comments and solutions are appreciated

The Error look like this.
[image]
**NOTE:**
There were some other tables like admin_user where I removed the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attribute and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    from the 2nd column of the DB Table.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.6 is the minimum supported version.  Your server might have a lesser version (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) You can check the version running the following query on your server:

```
SELECT version();
```

Comment: The live version is 5.5.41-log. Is there no other way to install Magento2 on live server?

Comment: No :( either request mysql be upgraded or switch hosting.
Reasons for using 5.6 : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1244